# Adding text over matrix in LaTeX

Tags: matrices, align

I am trying to accomplish this in LaTeX.

```
        j
    ⎡a  b  c⎤
    |d  e  f|
    ⎣h  i  j⎦
```

so that the "j" is aligned with the center of the matrix.

It seems like I can't use the `\begin{align}` in LaTeX while also using the `\begin{matrix}` environment, because any `&` inside the matrix environment will not apply to the align environment

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another array around the matrix should do the trick:

```
\begin{array}{c}
  j \\
  \left[
  \begin{array}{ccc}
    a & b & c \\
    d & e & f \\
    h & i & j % you forgot g! ;)
  \end{array}
  \right]
\end{array}
```